# Insert into syntax wrong

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i want to add new user into the access database using vb but it keeps saying wrong insert into syntax when i execute it. can anybody tell me whats wrong with it? ive searched for the mistakes and i think the code is not wrong. help me please

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Adduser
Private Sub createbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles createbtn.Click
    If required() = True Then
        Return
    End If


    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Gio\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSS\CSS\bin\Debug\CSS.accdb;")
    Try
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then connection.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "insert into User(Names,Username,Password,isAdmin) values (@Names, @Username, @Password, False)"
        Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

        Dim isAdmin As Boolean

        Dim Names As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Names", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        Names.Value = namebox.Text.ToString()
        command.Parameters.Add(Names)

        Dim Username As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Username", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        Username.Value = unamebox.Text.ToString()
        command.Parameters.Add(Username)

        Dim Password As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Password", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        Password.Value = namebox.Text.ToString()
        command.Parameters.Add(Password)

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isAdmin", isAdmin)
        isAdmin = False

        If command.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
            connection.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("New user is added!")
            namebox.Text = ""
            unamebox.Text = ""
            passbox.Text = ""

        Else
            MsgBox("Addition of new user failed!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Data Error")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` and `Password` are both [reserved words](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/sql-reserved-words-HP001032249.aspx) in Access so you should surround them with square brackets `[User]` or rename them.

Comment: ive change the user into something else. and the password also. but it still says insert into syntax error

Comment: **Add** your revised code and the full error message at the bottom of your original post. If you are not able to edit then put relevant details in a comment.

Comment: ..but, you don't have an **isAdmin** parameter.

Comment: i have it there @Andy G. below password parameter. but i dont know whether it is wrong or correct. since it is in boolean data type and im quite confused on how to make it